# Curl request to EC2 Instance from Godady server refusing conection

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I am sending curl request from godady's server to EC2 instance then every time I am getting connection refused error. But when I try the same code from another server or from localhost its working fine.

```
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy_IP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
echo '<pre>';print_r($output);
```

[image: security group]

ip to curl : http://52.11.185.159:1337/tree?user_id=1

Comment: What do the security group rules look like for this instance?

Comment: It's possible the IP is blacklisted. Try curling google. If you can curl google, it's more than likely than not the godaddy IP is blacklisted. Post the IP too and I'll try from and EC2 :)

Comment: Ihave mention the ip u can check